# Outputting array to Excel without duplicates

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, visual-studio

I was hoping you guys could help me to understand why my code is giving me this output.

Here's my problem: I'm trying to export an string array to Excel; this is the code I'm using:

```
Excel.Application oXL;
Excel.Workbook oWB;
Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
Excel.Range oRng;

oXL = new Excel.Application();
oWB = (oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

oXL.Visible = true;
oXL.UserControl = true;

oRng = oSheet.get_Range("A1");
oRng.Value2 = c;
```

This will create a file with just the first string from the array, so then I added to the code the following modification:

```
oRng = oSheet.get_Range("A1").get_Resize(c.GetLongLength(0), c.GetLongLength(0));
```

After that change I get 409 rows and 409 columns (409 is the size of the array) (also variable `c` is my string array).

Why is this happening? I'm assuming is because of `c.GetLongLength` but it would be helpful if someone could help me to understand the logic why this is happening. I'm fairly new in C# and coding in general so please don't be haters lol ;)

Comment: What is your desired outcome, I can't really tell from the question.  It looks like you are trying to set Value2 of your range to your entire array?  What do you want your range to be, and what do you want the value of each cell in that range to be?

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified that better, I'm trying to output the array "c" to excel where each cell in column "A" is a value of "c" but instead of doing that my code is setting each value in a different column and repeating that on each row using the legth of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer why this is happening, you need to understand what GetLongLength does.
[GetLongLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlonglength(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the number of elements in the Array as a Long (int64).  You are resizing the range to be 409 rows (the first argument of Get_Resize) and 409 Columns (the second argument of Get_Resize).

Additionally, instead of using get_Resize, it looks like you should probably use [ResizeProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.resize(v=vs.120).aspx).  `oRng = oSheet.get_Range("A1").Resize[c.GetLongLength(0), c.GetLongLength(1)];`

UPDATE: Now that I understand your question:

What you need to do is iterate through the array and set each value of the cell you want to the next value in the array.

Try this:

```
        oXL.ScreenUpdating = false;
        oRng = oSheet.get_Range("A1").Resize[c.GetLongLength(0),1];
        for(long x=1; x<=c.GetLongLength(0); x++)
        {
            oRng.Cells.Item[x, 1] = c[x - 1];
        }
        oXL.ScreenUpdating = true;
```

Disable Screen updating for performance.  There may be a better way to do this, but this will get you the result you want.  This also assumes you will only want Column A.  If you want other columns, you will have to code for that.

Comment: Max number of Rows in Excel version 2007 and later is 2^20, so Long type would be appropriate in general case.

Comment: I tried but I keep getting 409 rows and 409 columns :(

Comment: I'm giving you the Answer to this because not only you were able to explain it but you were able to show me how to sort it so it would displayed in one column! Thanks a lot @DontThinkJustGo  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code as follows:

```
oRng = oSheet.get_Range("A1").get_Resize(c.GetLongLength(0), 1);
```

or more general:

```
oRng = oSheet.get_Range("A1").get_Resize(c.GetLongLength(0), c.GetLongLength(1));
```

Alternatively you may use Resize method as prompted later, but correct the second dimension index:

```
oRng = oSheet.get_Range("A1").Resize(c.GetLongLength(0), c.GetLongLength(1))
```

And a short notation, something like that (in VBA):

```
Range("A1").Resize(UBound(c, 1), UBound(c, 2)).Value = c
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I tried that earlier and I get this exception: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Comment: See the amended answer. It also would be useful if you describe your array (1d, 2d, whatever). Rgds,

Comment: your answer is correct, I had to modified it a little bit though. This is what I end up doing:  oRng = oSheet.get_Range("A1").Resize[1, c.GetLongLength(0)];  I had to omitted the rows part of it :) thanks Tho! you gave me the light lol